# Algorithm for describing chess positions

Tags: python, performance, chess

I have an interesting problem with my chess application. The application reads PGN files, and at any time while viewing a game from the file, the function below, when called, iterates over the chessboard, gets the square names for each piece, and then constructs a string containing the description of which piece is where.

The function runs without errors, however it has a slight issue with respect to its performance: When the chess board is full, or close to full with 32 pieces, it runs pretty fast. Once the pieces go off the board and there remains a handful of pieces to describe, the function returns with a delay of around half a second. I have not tested the function with performance tools, but one can feel there is something strange going on: given the length of the function and its algorithm (please don't swear reading it), I can't understand why it will run faster when the board is full and slower when it's close to empty.

Can anyone spot what causes this issue? In addition, what can I try to optimize it?

```
def pos_text():  
    global node  
    #Dictionary of piece symbols to store their location on the board  
    d = {"K": [], "Q": [], "R": [], "B": [], "N": [], "P": [], "k": [], "q": [], "r":   [], "b": [], "n": [], "p": []}
    piece_letters = "KkQqRrNnBbPp"  
    #Iterates over the board and assigns square names to the individual piece symbols in d  
    for x in range(64):  
        sq = str(node.board().piece_at(x))  
        if sq in piece_letters:  
            d[sq].append(chess.SQUARE_NAMES[x])  
    # now makes a string containing the description of pieces:  
    pos = "White pieces:\nKing: %s\n" % d["K"][0]  
    if d["Q"]:  
        pos += "Queens: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["Q"]) if len(d["Q"]) >= 2 else "Queen: %s\n" % d["Q"][0]  
    if d["R"]:  
        pos += "Rooks: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["R"]) if len(d["R"]) >= 2 else "Rook: %s\n" % d["R"][0]  
    if d["B"]:  
        pos += "Bishops: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["B"]) if len(d["B"]) >= 2 else "Bishop: %s\n" % d["B"][0]  
    if d["N"]: 
        pos += "Knights: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["N"]) if len(d["N"]) >= 2 else "Knight: %s\n" % d["N"][0]  
    if d["P"]:  
        pos += "Pawns: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["P"]) if len(d["P"]) >= 2 else "Pawn: %s\n" % d["P"][0]  
    pos += "Black pieces:\nKing: %s\n" % d["k"][0]  
    if d["q"]:  
        pos += "Queens: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["q"]) if len(d["q"]) >= 2 else "Queen: %s\n" % d["q"][0]  
    if d["r"]:  
        pos += "Rooks: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["r"]) if len(d["r"]) >= 2 else "Rook: %s\n" % d["r"][0]  
    if d["b"]:  
        pos += "Bishops: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["b"]) if len(d["b"]) >= 2 else "Bishop: %s\n" % d["b"][0]  
    if d["n"]:  
        pos += "Knights: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["n"]) if len(d["n"]) >= 2 else "Knight: %s\n" % d["n"][0]  
    if d["p"]:  
        pos += "Pawns: %s\n" % ", ".join(d["p"]) if len(d["p"]) >= 2 else "Pawn: %s\n" % d["p"][0]  
    return pos
```

Comment: In general, loading global is pretty expensive. What happens if you make the board an argument to pos_text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The slowness when having fewer pieces

Having fewer pieces on the board will make this slower:

> ```
> piece_letters = "KkQqRrNnBbPp"  
> for x in range(64):  
>     sq = str(node.board().piece_at(x))  
>     if sq in piece_letters:  
>         d[sq].append(chess.SQUARE_NAMES[x])
> ```

Consider these two (invalid) extremes:

- When the board is full of `K`, the evaluation of `sq in piece_letters` will terminate with `True` after checking the first letter
- When the board is empty, the evaluation of `sq in piece_letters` will have to check each letter in `piece_letters` until it can terminate with `False`

In the rest of the code,
there are more evaluations performed in the full case compared to the empty case,
but not enough to outweigh the effects of the `sq in piece_letters` check,
due to the length of `piece_letters`.

Changing `piece_letters` to this would help:

```
piece_letters = frozenset("KkQqRrNnBbPp")
```

This way the evaluation of `sq in piece_letters` won't have to step through all letters.

But actually, since you already have a dictionary with the possible pieces in `d`,
you don't need `piece_letters` at all,
you can use simply this:

```
for x in range(64):  
    sq = str(node.board().piece_at(x))  
    if sq in d:  
        d[sq].append(chess.SQUARE_NAMES[x])
```

This is also better for another reason:
if `d` doesn't have a predefined `[]` value for the `sq` key,
then the original code wouldn't work anyway.
When you write it this way,
it's clear that `d[sq]` exists, and will not raise a `KeyError`,
so it's more coherent and readable.

Actually the `piece_letters` string can be useful to initialize `d` itself:

```
piece_letters = "KkQqRrNnBbPp"  
d = dict((c, []) for c in piece_letters)
```

And `d` is a very poor name. `pieces` would be better.

#### Other optimizations

Avoid using `global` variables if possible.
It would be better to pass `node.board()` to the method if possible.
Actually it seems the method should belong to the board itself,
and I would rename it to `print_board`.

The printing of the pieces is very repetitive.
It would be better to extract their logic to a helper function, for example:

```
def format_piece(marker, single_name, plural_name):
    num = len(pieces[marker])
    if num:
        label = plural_name if num >= 2 else single_name
        return "%s: %s\n" % (label, ", ".join(pieces[marker]))
    return ''

pos = "White pieces:\nKing: %s\n" % d["K"][0]  
pos += format_piece('Q', 'Queen', 'Queens')
pos += format_piece('R', 'Rook', 'Rooks')
# ...
```

This achieves 2 additional optimizations:

1. Count the length of each `pieces[marker]` only once
2. Avoid duplication in the formatting, by setting `label`

Answer (score 1):

I have now changed the function as follows and it works as I want. It is indeed costly to refer a global variable 64 times. It turns out iterating over piece_letters in the first version was not the problem either though it was redundant. But when copying the global name node with a local one it runs like a breeze.

```
def get_pos():  
    n = node.board()  
    d = {"K": [], "Q": [], "R": [], "B": [], "N": [], "P": [], "k": [], "q": [], "r": [], "b": [], "n": [], "p": []}  
    for x in range(64):  
        sq = str(n.piece_at(x))  
        if sq != 'None':  
            d[sq].append(chess.SQUARE_NAMES[x])  
    pos = "White pieces:\nKing: %s\n" % d["K"][0]  
    pos += format_pos(d["Q"], "Queen", "Queens")  
    pos += format_pos(d["R"], "Rook", "Rooks")  
    pos += format_pos(d["B"], "Bishop", "Bishops")  
    pos += format_pos(d["N"], "Knight", "Knights")  
    pos += format_pos(d["P"], "Pawn", "Pawns")  
    pos += "Black pieces:\nKing: %s\n" % d["k"][0]  
    pos += format_pos(d["q"], "Queen", "Queens")  
    pos += format_pos(d["r"], "Rook", "Rooks")  
    pos += format_pos(d["b"], "Bishop", "Bishops")  
    pos += format_pos(d["n"], "Knight", "Knights")  
    pos += format_pos(d["p"], "Pawn", "Pawns")  
    return pos  

def format_pos(lst, sing, pl):  
    num = len(lst)  
    if num:  
        label = U"%s: %s\n" % (pl, ", ".join(l)) if num >= 2 else U"%s: %s\n" % (sing, lst[0])  
        return label  
    else:  
        return ""
```